Movie about kids searching for lizard man
This movie I can barely recall, so I'm sorry for the skimpy details, I'll try to remember more
There was a group of kids, three I believe, a skinny boy, a chubby boy, and a skinny girl. it looked early-to-mid-2000s, probably American, i would say it's a fantasy drama, but it's hard to pin a genre 
I believe they were searching for a mythical lizard or alligator man in the forest near their town, and I think the chubby boy gets deathly injured by something near the end, and then the lizard/alligator man shows up and heals him somehow, then the town learns its real (possibly from people who injured the chubby boy?) and get a mob together to kill it, but then the kids come out with the creature and convince them it's not dangerous. 
if I recall correctly the film did NOT have very good effects, and the creature was poor CGI, though I could be mixing up memories on that part
EDIT: Actually! It's possible the skinny kid was injured by someone while in the town, and the lizard man came out of the forest and saved his life, convincing the town it wasn't dangerous

You probably mean Legend Of Gator Face's not-so-convincing puppet.

Yes, that's it, I clearly got some details wrong the boy was in a burning building, not injured, and the gator creature was injured and healed by the swamp, not sure why I thought it was CGI.

OK, I'll put it up. I thought this was asked before, but I can't find it. Glad you found it.

This is the plot of The Legend of Gator Face from 1996.

Two friends, Danny (John White), and Phil (Dan Warry-Smith) live in a Mississippi town near a swamp. There is a local legend of a swamp-dwelling creature called "Gator Face". They construct a Gator Face costume by modifying a wetsuit. After scaring most of the townsfolk, the pranks make national news, drawing the attention of the National Guard. Danny soon discovers that Gator Face is real and friendly. After Danny, along with his friends Phil and Angel (Charlotte Sullivan), saves Gator Face from a trap, they realize that Gator Face is protecting the swamps.

Here's the trailer:




Dude, you are such a life saver, I've been trying to remember all these for years now.
